# Orika: customize MappingFacade

Tags: java, orika

2 classes:User and UserDto.
Its have fields, which differ from the the point of in User fields set with underlining (for example: "first_name"), then in UserDto - in CamelCase ("firstName").
I have a task to map fields from User to UserDto, using MapperFacade:

```
  MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
  UserDto userDto = mapper.map(user, UserDto.class);
```

But this does not work - as I understand the reason is difference of styles. In UserDto keys for mapping with CamelCase, and in User - without CamelCase.

Is there any way to customize the mapping so that underlining or Camel case will be ignored?

I considered Orica-Converter, but I cant understand, how It can help me in solving of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by applying different mapper - ModelMapper.
The solution have founded during 0,5 hours and is as follows:

```
 ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.getConfiguration()
            .setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE)
            .setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.CAMEL_CASE);
```

That's all! ))